# Connect the python app to a database using centos 7

Tags: python, mysql, centos7

I am new to all this I have apython app already helo.mysql.py and need to Connect the python app to a database.  I am using centos 7 and have it installed on a ec2 instance if anyone can help please help.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Did you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect to any database from Python app, first we need to install the respective db driver package.

pip install MySQLdb

Then import this module in your Python code, connect to database and perform CRUD operations.